# Pandas DataFrame Time Conversion

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to change for example '01:31:41' the value display in stopwatch which is into seconds value. E.g this is 1 min and 31 second, so roughly about 91 seconds.

Comment: what bit of this has to do with pandas or dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

split string into a list object
create a timedelta object without miliseconds as they aren't needed
we use the self method of timedelta total_seconds()

```
from datetime import timedelta
original_time_string = "01:30:12"
list_string = original_time_string.split(":")
print((timedelta(minutes=int(list_string[0]),seconds=int(list_string[1])).total_seconds()))
```